# Reset git branch to a specific commit and keep stashed changes (Using Git Extensions)

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-extensions, git-reset

[image]

As stated on the title. I was wondering what happens when I select the `Reset current branch to here`. I've stashed all the changes I made and want to:

1. Revert the branch to a specific commit,
2. Merge changes from another branch, then
3. Use `Stash pop` to bring back my changes and commit.

Will my stashed changes be lost? Is `Rebase current branch` the best option instead?

[image]

When resetting, should I select Soft, Mixed or Hard?

Thank you.

**Solution** - I selected `Reset branch to here` and chose `Hard Reset`. Obviously sorted out a few merge conflicts and used `Stash pop` and committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your stash is kept separately and will not be lost.

If you want to play it safe, you can use `git stash apply` which will not remove it after applying, unlike `git stash pop`. This way you are able to apply it to a different commit again later.

Comment: When resetting, should it be soft, mixed or hard?

Comment: A soft reset keeps everything in the working tree like it is, a hard reset will actually reset everything to the repository version. If I understand correctly what you are trying to achive, you need a hard reset here. [Read the documentation for more info](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Instead of stashing you could also create another branch, commit your pending changes then reset to another revision.